Migrating Users From One Supabase Project to Another
I'm new to Supabase and migration databases.
I need to bring users from project A to project B but I'm not sure how to do that.
I took a look at this link:
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/platform/migrating-and-upgrading-projects#migrate-your-project
But I don't want to migrate all the tables and stuff (I've already created new tables on the new database and I don't want it overwritten by project A).
I've also noticed some people already made user accounts on project B.
How can I get the users from Project A and bring them over to Project B? I saw some old instructions about possibly exporting and importing but I don't see that anymore and some say to upload the CSV but the table is protected now.
Thank you in advance!
